# No value present - cucumber json data driven

Tags: java, json, cucumber, data-driven-tests

I've got a problem with data driven testing in cucumber. I want to get data from json file. I've prepared scenario:

```
Feature: data provider
Scenario Outline: Data driven using json file
Given account user
And Get System Variables
And Delete TB report if already exist
When user navigates to TB report
Then Select Filters On Reports Page from <data>
Example:
|data|
|test|
```

**Data json object:**

```
[
{
"fundName": "test",
"currentDate": "31/12/2020"
},
"fundName": "test2",
"currentDate": "31/12/2020"
}
```

**Pojo class for storing data:**

```
public class Data {

public String fundName;
public String currentDate;
}
```

**Data json reader:**

```
private final String path = "path/to/file";
private List<Data> data;

public JsonDataReader(){
    DataList = getData();
}


private List<Data> getData() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
    try {
        bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        Data[] data= gson.fromJson(bufferReader, Data[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Json file not found at path : " + path);
    }finally {
        try { if(bufferReader != null) bufferReader.close();}
        catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }
}
    
public final Data getDataByName(String name){
     return dataList.stream().filter(x -> x.fundName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findAny().get();
}
```

**Step definition:**

```
@Then("Select Filters On Reports Page from \\\"(.*)\\\"$")
public void selectMultipleFilters(String name) {
Data data = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getJsonDataReader().getFundByName(name);
reportSteps.selectMultipleFiltersForReports(data);
}
```

But when I try to run this I've got an error on 5th step:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at JsonDataReader.getDataByName
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd try debugging/logging what the `name` parameter is that gets actually passed to `getDataByName()`. (the `NoSuchElementException` is probably from the `.get()`, which means your filter did not match any elements of `dataList`.

Comment: Ok., I've change this method to:
public final Data getDataByName(String name) {
for (Data data : dataList) {
if (data.fundName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
return data;
}
return null;
}
}
Error stopped apppearing but now I've got NPE even though the data is in a json file

Comment: Have you tried the by printing the values in `for (Data data : dataList)` loop?

Comment: Is issue resolved?

Comment: Hi, null pointer exception no longer appears, but the parameter that is taken from the json file is not taken into account by the script and the following exception appears: no such element exception